# Can React-Native: 0.64.3 target for Android 12?

Tags: android, react-native

I am using `React-Native: 0.64.3` and targeting `Android 11`. Now, I would like to target my app to `Android 12` without upgrading `React-Native`.

But, In `React-Native: 0.66` release notes it's been mentioned that,

> Today we’re releasing React Native v0.66 for Android 12 and iOS 15 support alongside fixes and general updates.

[Source:](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2021/10/01/version-066)

Does it mean we must use `React-Native: 0.66` in order to target `Android 12`? OR

Can I target `Android 12` being in `React-Native: 0.64.3` itself?

Answer (score 0):

i changed rn 0.64.3 for support api 31 by changing the `build.gradel` file (`app/build.gradel`)
`buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0" minSdkVersion = 22 compileSdkVersion = 31 targetSdkVersion = 31 ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"`
and `dependencies { classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4') classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3') }`
in `gradel-wrapper.properties` change `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip`
and in `app/gradel.properties` add `org.gradle.java.home=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home` for java 11
i change code `native_module.gradel` (`@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_module.gradel`)
`ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>[] packages = this.reactNativeModules` to `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> packages = this.reactNativeModules`
if you using react-native-reanimated v1 upgrade to `"react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.4"` and add `configurations { customConfig.extendsFrom implementation }`
and change `classpath+=files(project.getConfigurations().getByName('compile').asList()` to `classpath+=files(project.getConfigurations().getByName('customConfig')`.asList()) in `react-native-reanimated/android/build.gradel`
I hope this helps

Comment: and in androidmanifest.xml add android:exported="true" or android:exported="false"  
[link] (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element?hl=id)

Comment: We should properly format our answers so they are helpful to the readers. This answer is too difficult to read and understand and destroys the purpose of this community.

Comment: There is no app/build.gradel file and so on.... Please format your answer